# How to type hint a return an instance of a subclass from a list of superclass in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

If I have a class that stores a list of superclasses, and I have a method that filters out a specific subclass types, how can I set the type hint to say that the method returns a list of the subclass?

Example:

```
from typing import List


class Color:
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Green(Color):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('green')

    def do_a_green(self):
        pass


class Blue(Color):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('blue')

    def do_a_blue(self):
        pass


class ColorList:
    _color_list: List[Color]

    def get_blue_colors(self) -> List[Blue]:
        return [color for color in self._color_list
                if color.name == 'blue'] # <- error: List comprehension has
                                         # incompatible type List[Color]; expected List[Blue]
```

Comment: you have a typo in your example, `'green'` -> `'blue'`. And this likely isn't possible as you've written it. In general you can't define types based on values (there are workarounds like `Literal` but I'm not going to recommend them)

Comment: indeed, your typo is a perfect example of why `get_blue_colors` is unsafe

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is probably with a TypeGuard.

```
from typing import List
from typing_extensions import TypeGuard

class Color:
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Green(Color):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('green')

    def do_a_green(self):
        pass


class Blue(Color):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('blue')

    def do_a_blue(self):
        pass

def _is_blue(color: Color) -> TypeGuard[Blue]:
    return color.name == "blue"

class ColorList:
    _color_list: List[Color]

    def get_blue_colors(self) -> List[Blue]:
        return [color for color in self._color_list
                if _is_blue(color)]
```

Or use cast:

```
    def get_blue_colors(self) -> List[Blue]:
        return cast(List[Blue], [color for color in self._color_list
                if color.name == "blue"])
```

*Edit*:

Or use `isinstance`:

```
def get_blue_colors(self) -> List[Blue]:
        return [color for color in self._color_list
                if isinstance(color, Blue)])
```

Comment: `import TypeGaurd` -> `import TypeGuard`

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.  I was trying to think about the "right" way to do this, e.g. if I was in Java, and it would either have to be a cast or storing these subclasses in different lists and then returning a combined superclass list for operations that only need the superclass.  But it's good to know what my options are.

Comment: Note that `cast` does not do any type-checking though. You can cast whatever - it is just a message to the type checkers. E.g.: `a = cast(int, "hello")` - neither python interpreter nor type checkers will complain. Type checkers will think `type(a) == int` and when executing `a` will be `"hello"` (and `type(a)` will just be `str`).